# Image not showing up in screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a background image to `Container`. I added the image to a images folder and in the `pubspec` file.

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_bloc: ^0.20.0
  equatable: ^0.3.0
  meta: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.2.3895

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/banner.png
```

I used `DecorationImage`.

```
class _ImageBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 140.0,
      width: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          image: AssetImage('images/banner.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything seems fine to me, it does not give any error but the image does not show up on the screen. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

During last week I tried everything and failed only for it to work with different mobile. When I debug it with Samsumg Galaxy A5 the image does not show up. But with J7 max the image appears on screen fine. Can anyone tell me why is this hapenning.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the methods below:

Try to give the image some width:

```dart
class _ImageBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 140.0,
      width: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          image: AssetImage('images/banner.png'),
          width: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Try to check the path and the name of the image in the `pubscpec.yaml`

Hope it helps you!

Comment: width not use!!

Answer (score 0):

using ExactAssetImage

```
class _ImageBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 140.0,
      width: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          image: ExactAssetImage('images/banner.png', ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```